# How to send an email to requester only if the build is triggered manually?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, email-ext

I would like to configure a project in Jenkins to send emails to the recipients group for regular scheduled builds, but only to the requester in case the build is triggered manually. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this by using the "Script - After Build" trigger of the Editable Email Notification post-build action. You can run a groovy script, with the last line evaluating to a Boolean, which determines whether or not to send the email. The screenshot below shows the trigger section that checks to see if the build was initiated by a user (manually).

[image]

This script will only tell you whether or not the IMMEDIATE cause of the build was a manual user action, though. Depending on how your build pipeline is setup, one of your upstream jobs may have been initiated manually, so I'm not sure if you want an email sent in that case. If you do, you will have to iterate through all the build causes and look for a manual cause.

```
def boolean wasStartedManually(causes) {
    boolean manuallyStarted = false
    causes.each { cause ->
        if (cause.class == hudson.model.Cause$UserIdCause) {
            manuallyStarted = true
        }

        if (!manuallyStarted) {
            if (cause.class == hudson.model.Cause$UpstreamCause) {
                manuallyStarted = wasStartedManually(cause.upstreamCauses)
            }      
        }


    }
    return manuallyStarted
}

wasStartedManually(build.getCauses())
```

You will need to add 2 post-build Email actions to your job, one for when the job is triggered manually, and then another if the job was not submitted manually. For the latter, you would run the same script, but just negate the results.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly! The first (simpler) solution was enough for me.